# Why doesn't `adb shell input tap` command work in a emulator

Tags: android, adb

I am running `Pixel 6 pro` on Android emulator from MacOS. And I have enabled USB developer mode in the virtual device. I tried to run `adb shell input tag x y` command:

```
adb  -s emulator-5556 shell input tap 25690 8496
```

it doesn't return any error but there is nothing happened on the virtual device. I wonder what I did wrong.

below is the version of adb:

```
> adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 34.0.4-10411341
Installed as /opt/homebrew/bin/adb
Running on Darwin 22.2.0 (arm64)
```

I use below command to get the `x, y` coordinator

```
> adb  -s emulator-5556 shell getevent -l
/dev/input/event1: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000645A
/dev/input/event1: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00002130
/dev/input/event1: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_PRESSURE      00000400
/dev/input/event1: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
/dev/input/event1: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_PRESSURE      00000000
/dev/input/event1: EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   ffffffff
/dev/input/event1: EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
```

I take the value from `ABS_MT_POSITION_X    0000645A ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    00002130` and convert it to decimal value.

Comment: Isn't the number `25690`  for x a bit high? Ty my understanding x and y are the pixel coordinate of the virtual tap you want to execute. Using your screen coordinates the screen would be a 218k screen (or even larger).

Comment: I am using this command to get x and y `adb  -s emulator-5556 shell getevent -l`. I have put the output of this command in the post.